# Adding Search/Filter to Swagger UI for filtering endpoints

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

We have swagger api documentation integrated to spring boot and right now and using swagger-ui-react": "3.30.1" to display SwaggerUI (default /api-docs). There are so many controllers/endpoints to scroll so instead we are looking to have a search bar or filter to search/filter endpoints. Does anyone know how can I implement this, is there any in built feature?  Below is the example for what I am looking for

Example :

Comment: `Swagger-UI` is open source, you can read the sources customize it and build you own version https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api

Comment: If it's not implemented yet, a `JS` filter might be a good solution.

Comment: The documentation mentions a Display Config variable `filter` that, when set to `true`,  should provide a UI component for filtering.  However, I'm unable to get it to appear, so YMMV.

https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/